# comet server and network latency time

Tags: networking, node.js, tcp, comet, latency

For a social site we use a node.js based comet server as the instant messenger, everything is working great we have only one problem how to solve the latency problem to Australia and New Zealand where we have RRT between 310 ms to 440 ms.

One idea is to have local servers, but in this case they must connect to the main server that a user in Australia is able to communicate with one from the UK. This comet-comet connection will have a higher latency too, but local users can chat fast which will be mostly the case.

Has anyone a better idea then use of a local comet servers?

Answer (score 1):

If your latency is due to the geographical distance, there is no option how to shorten it. The only thing you can do is try find upstream network providers who have more "straight" cables. But you can never achieve latency shorter than direct air distance between those 2 countries/servers.

If you will have users in Australia communicating with each other, then yes, it will be a difference for them if they will be connecting to a local server. But for communication between one user in UK and one in AU, it won't matter if you have a local server.

But anyway for an instant messenger the latency is not so important IMHO. The recipient does not know the moment when the sender finished his message and hit the send button, so he can't measure the latency. And human is not able to send multiple messages per second, so I think it won't be possible to see the difference between 400 ms and 10 ms latency. If it would be over 1 second, it could be visible...

So to summarize I would bother with making local servers only when there would be enough local users communicating between themselves.

(Please let me know if some of my assumptions about your setup were incorrect.)